# Can A php file get another's session?

Tags: php, web

I have a simple website build in php+mysql, I want to integrate some login module like [phplogin](https://github.com/panique/php-login).I simply create a hyperlink in my website linking to it's index.php file, then I back to my site the user login information doesn't exist. I think I don't get the session in the phplogin module. How can I get this imformation?

Comment: Check for differences in the subdomain, `www.yoursite.com` is different from `yoursite.com`

Comment: Each page needs the session_start(); function to access any session variables http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 2):

Yes you will get these values until session has not been destroyed.

Comment: This is true but what about www.example.com and example.com?

Answer (score 0):

Each php document that requires access to the session variables should contain the function `session_start();`

a variable can be set with `$_SESSION['your_var']="foo";`

and read with `$your_var=$_SESSION['your_var'];`

This way session variables are accessible across php documents

Answer (score 0):

It depends. For example. If you have two URLs.
http://site.example.com/ and http://www.example.com/site/ (both are the same directory in public_html) and you set `$_SESSION['test']` on http://site.example.com/, it will **NOT** be visible on http://www.example.com/site/. 
You could make the sessions cross subdomain but that's another question.